# Query select from Amazon Redshift using a lambda function nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-redshift

I need to query from a table in our dw on Amazon Redshift. I've been reading but can't find a way to query from a table in there, i usually do this to connect using sequelize.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_REDSHIFT,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASS,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    ...process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'dev' && {
      logging: false,
    },
    define: {
      underscored: true,
    },
    dialectOptions: {
      multipleStatements: true,
      dateStrings: true,
      typeCast: (field, next) => {
        if (field.type === 'DATETIME' || field.type === 'TIMESTAMP') {
          return field.string();
        }
        return next();
      },
    },
    pool: {
      max: 1,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000,
    },
  },
);

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter((file) => {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach((file) => {
  const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

but i get `SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`, i have tried using the endpoint, jdbc and odbc, i'm really new on this so anything would be helpfull.